# How to html escape special character on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I want to parse special characters (read from a file) to HTML format. For example

```
**üö ä€ afd sdf sdfüäää**
```

to

```
<p>&uuml;&ouml; &auml;&euro; afd sdf sdf&uuml;&auml;&auml;&auml;&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</p>
```

I found few solution on web:

**Rack::Utils.escape_html()**

**CGI::escapeHTML()**

**ERB::Util.html_escape()**

Each of them is doing fine with normal text:

```
HI"ksdlfj</?>>>.dsfklsd
```

to

```
<p>HI"ksdlfj&lt;/?&gt;&gt;&gt;.dsfklsd</p>
```

But it doesn't do anything, when I have those special characters in input text.

Any help on this?

Rails Version: 3.0.5
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p429

Thanks,
Chandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use htmlentities

```
require 'htmlentities'
str = "üö ä€ afd sdf sdfüäää"
HTMLEntities.new.encode(str, :named)

#=> "&uuml;&ouml; &auml;&euro; afd sdf sdf&uuml;&auml;&auml;&auml;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with:

`while str.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''); end`

But because I only needed 0-9 and a-z. Hope this helps!